# Spring CrudRepository not working save & delete operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In Spring, CrudRepository findAll() operation working good for fetching data from the database but with the same configuration in case of saving, update & delete it's not working.

**EmployeeService.java**

```
 @Service
    public class EmployeeService {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeRepo employeeRepoI;

        @Transactional
        public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
            return (List<Employee>) employeeRepoI.findAll();
        }

        @Transactional
        public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
            return (Employee) employeeRepoI.findOne(id);
        }

        @Transactional
        public Employee addEmployee(Employee employee) {
            return (Employee) employeeRepoI.save(employee);
        }

        @Transactional
        public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
            return (Employee) employeeRepoI.save(employee);

        }

        @Transactional
        public void deleteEmployee(int id) {
             employeeRepoI.delete(id);
        }

    }
```

**EmployeeRapo.java**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo<T, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

    List<Employee> findAll();


}
```

Comment: Remove `<T, ID extends Serializable>` from the declaration of `EmployeeRepo`

Comment: @sergey i have removed this and make ID as Long, but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have CrudRepository with Long type and deleteEmployee with primitive int. This values should match.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by **@Sergey** Your `EmployeeRepo` has a wrong definition there

Try this

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
    List<Employee> findAll();
}
```

Also your `deleteEmployee()` method takes an `int` while it should take `Long` as a parameter.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteEmployee(Long id) {
    employeeRepoI.delete(id);
}
```

Comment: I have tried both the suggestions still the same problem

Comment: There are no error coming, that's in server logs or anywhere on console